# Adding an index to elasticsearch and creating a term join in Kibana maps

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to create a chloropleth in Kibana like in the tutorial here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/maps-add-choropleth-layer.html

I cannot figure out how to add an index and have that index available when doing a term join in the Kibana map page.

I am creating my index like this in the Dev Tools page...
[image]

Then I am creating a map in the Kibana maps page.
I create a layer and click the plus icon to create a term join. I do not see my new "congressional-polygons" index in this dropdown. Why not?

[image]

Is there straightforward example or tutorial anywhere that explains how to add your own index (not sample data) to Elastic Cloud / Kibana and then use this index when creating a map? Our goal is to pull the colorval variable from the index to create a dynamic style on the map layer. In other words, we'd like to display the regions as a chloropleth where color represents the colorval variable.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to use your own data is create a keyword field that uses two letter country codes as defined in the [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

This way documents will be tied to a geo-code like "JP" for Japan. Kibana will know to take this code and "join" the document on the geo tag keyword provided in the document set.

Once documents in the indices that are included in the index pattern you choose to join on have a keyword field that contains the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code, then the countries with a higher aggregate value of documents from a specific country code will appear darker.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue is that my index doesn't appear in the EMS term joins right source dropdown. I  just added a 2 letter country code to my index. The index still does not appear in the dropdown. Here is an example of a document in my index:       {
        "_index" : "newindex5",
        "_type" : "default",
        "_id" : "IFOb-W8BNQ4iHt4UcM4Z",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "geo_shape" : "10",
          "geo_point" : "1",
          "country_code" : "US"
        }